# osgi in webapplication

Tags: osgi

I want to develop one web application using jsp and servlet. Now my doubt is can I use osgi service for back end?
When I thought about this approach, I understood it is not possible
because in client side also we need the osgi plugins to acess the service. But still I need good expertise comments on this
approach.I know this can be achieved through eclipse RAP. please apologize if my question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why does your client need OSGi plugins to access your web applications? Isn't it accessed via a browser? Are you maybe talking about a *web service*? Why do you say it is not possible, and then go on to say *this can be achieved through eclipse RAP*? Can you please explain in more detail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your question completely. You can certainly develop a web application using OSGi. All you have to do is deploy your war file into the http service of your OSGi container (e.g. jetty in felix). Doing so can be a bit of a pain, though, so consider using [PAX-war-extender](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/WAR+Extender). Your clients won't care or even know that you are running OSGi.

That said, if you are developing purely a web app, it *might* not be worth to use OSGi, and you could simply deploy directly on apache/tomact/some application server instead.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can, check the [jetty osgi boot project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Jetty_OSGi).  you can develop you web part just as before you did! just add some osgi Metadata into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file. if you want to get some osgi services, you can use ServiceTrack just like osgi bundle did！ we have did it in this way！
hope it's help for you!